# C# DeserializeObject JSON

Tags: c#, xamarin, model-view-controller

Estoy tratando de convertir un json que recibo con un modelo para poder rederizar sus datos. No puedo convertirlo ni con Plan ni con PlanInfo.Pero cada que le mando mi modelo me null, alguien sabe porqué?

Esto es lo que tengo en método

```
private async void CallDataProject(string id) {

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    var response = await client.GetAsync
        ("https://trustfundapp.herokuapp.com/plan-json/" + id);

        switch (response.StatusCode)
        {

            case (System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK):

               // Msn.Text = "Datos recibidos con éxito";

                string xjson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                //<List<ProjectInfoJson>>
                var json_ = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PlanInfo>(xjson);

                    break;

            }
}
```

Este el string que obtengo del ReadAsStringAsync

> "{\"plan\":{\"id\":\"pqfdbtrl6uvtprzmpwqp\",\"name\":\"koko\",\"amount\":130,\"creation_date\":\"2019-05-23T08:58:28-05:00\",\"repeat_every\":2,\"repeat_unit\":\"week\",\"retry_times\":2,\"status\":\"active\",\"status_after_retry\":\"cancelled\",\"trial_days\":0,\"currency\":\"MXN\"}}"

este mi modelo

```
public class Plan
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int amount { get; set; }
    public DateTime creation_date { get; set; }
    public int repeat_every { get; set; }
    public string repeat_unit { get; set; }
    public int retry_times { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string status_after_retry { get; set; }
    public int trial_days { get; set; }
    public string currency { get; set; }
}


public class PlanInfo
{
    public Plan plan { get; set; }
}
```

y esto el json que recibo

```
{
"plan": {
    "id": "puzvyjkwi0nvpar30kfe",
    "name": "semanal test",
    "amount": 10,
    "creation_date": "2019-06-06T21:05:18-05:00",
    "repeat_every": 1,
    "repeat_unit": "week",
    "retry_times": 2,
    "status": "active",
    "status_after_retry": "unpaid",
    "trial_days": 5,
    "currency": "MXN"
}}
```

Comment: ¿Alguna respuesta te fue de utilidad?

Answer (score 0):

Probe el siguiente codigo

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main() {

        string xjson = @"{
                            'plan': {
                                'id': 'puzvyjkwi0nvpar30kfe',
                                'name': 'semanal test',
                                'amount': 10,
                                'creation_date': '2019-06-06T21:05:18-05:00',
                                'repeat_every': 1,
                                'repeat_unit': 'week',
                                'retry_times': 2,
                                'status': 'active',
                                'status_after_retry': 'unpaid',
                                'trial_days': 5,
                                'currency': 'MXN'
                            }
                        }";

        var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PlanInfo>(xjson);

        Console.WriteLine(json.plan.id);
    }
}
```

Y me deserializa correctamente, quiere decir que la definicion de las clases que utilizas son correctas, quizas el json que estas recibiendo no es el mismo que esperas deserializar

Despues de tu edicion realice la prueba

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main() {

        string xjson = "{\"plan\":{\"id\":\"pqfdbtrl6uvtprzmpwqp\",\"name\":\"koko\",\"amount\":130,\"creation_date\":\"2019-05-23T08:58:28-05:00\",\"repeat_every\":2,\"repeat_unit\":\"week\",\"retry_times\":2,\"status\":\"active\",\"status_after_retry\":\"cancelled\",\"trial_days\":0,\"currency\":\"MXN\"}}";

        var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PlanInfo>(xjson);

        Console.WriteLine(json.plan.id);
    }
}
```

y se obtiene el dato correctamente

Comment: voy a subir a la pregunta lo que me tira el  ReadAsStringAsync , a ver si notas algo raro ...

Comment: edite la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Considerando que la pregunta tiene código incompleto, la siguiente respuesta trata de emular el comportamiento del escenario:

```
private async void CallDataProject(string id) {

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

var response = await client.GetAsync
    ("https://trustfundapp.herokuapp.com/plan-json/" + id);

    switch (response.StatusCode)
    {

        case (System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK):

           // Msn.Text = "Datos recibidos con éxito";

            string xjson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            //<List<ProjectInfoJson>>
            var json_ = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PlanInfo>(xjson);

                break;

    }
   //Aqui falta un return y esto es importante para contestar preguntas. 
   //Código incompleto deja muchos vacíos y tenemos que estar en modo adivinos :D
}
```

Sucede que estás retornando la variable `json_` en lugar de la variable `xjson`

Cuando ya tienes un Json listo y lo vuelves a deserializar, es normal que te genere barras invertidas (backslashes)

```
"{\"plan\":{\"id\":\"pqfdbtrl6uvtprzmpwqp\",\"name\":\"koko\",\"amount\":130,\"creation_date\":\"2019-05-23T08:58:28-05:00\",\"repeat_every\":2,\"repeat_unit\":\"week\",\"retry_times\":2,\"status\":\"active\",\"status_after_retry\":\"cancelled\",\"trial_days\":0,\"currency\":\"MXN\"}}"
```

Comment: si fredy lo sé pero esta muy raro, no puedo convertirlo en objeto var json_ = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PlanInfo>(xjson); me da null todo el tiempo aunque le pase solo plan o planinfo

Comment: Edita la pregunta agregando todos los datos necesarios para reproducir tu escenario

Comment: los \" son el caracter de scape para poder poner las comillas dobles en un string